# csproj: how to get all resources?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, csproj

How to get all resources, which copies to created binary?

I think that it is all elements like this (has CopyToOutputDirectory tag):

```
<ItemGroup>
 <None Include="Configs\Config.config">
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
 </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

and like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Resource Include="Resources\Icons\icon4.png" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="Resources\Icons\icon5.png" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="Resources\Icons\icon6.png" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="icon7.ico" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="Resources\Icons\icon8.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And I should parse all elements with tag "Resource" like this (?):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        IEnumerable<XAttribute> attr = doc.Descendants().Attributes("Resource");
```

And another question- how to get element before CopyToOutputDirectory tag?

P.S. if it be useful- i have folder with projects(another folders).
I parse all .csproj files from this folders and generate XML file with list of resources which copied to compiled binary of each project.

Comment: Do you want the resources at Runtime? or Compile-time?

Comment: I just want to know list of resources.I parse csproj file and generate xml output with resourses(path) ,wich copies to binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project files are **NOT** simple XML files, they can contain logic which needs to be evaluated.

You can achieve that by using the `Microsoft.Build` assembly and the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation` namespace.

```
var project = new Project(@"..\..\StackOverflow.csproj");

        var itemsToCopy = new List<ProjectItem>();

        var projectItems = project.Items;
        foreach (var projectItem in projectItems)
        {
            // e.g get all elements with CopyToOutputDirectory == "Always"
            var projectMetadata = projectItem.GetMetadata("CopyToOutputDirectory");
            if (projectMetadata != null && projectMetadata.EvaluatedValue == "Always")
                itemsToCopy.Add(projectItem);
        }

        foreach (var projectItem in itemsToCopy)
        {
            // e.g get then Include-Attribute from <None Include="Configs\Config.config">
            var evaluatedInclude = projectItem.EvaluatedInclude;
        }

        // get the resources that are not set to CopyToOutputDirectory == "Always"
        var collection = project.GetItems("Resources");
        var resources = collection.Except(itemsToCopy);
        foreach (var projectItem in resources)
        {
            // e.g get then Include-Attribute from <Resource Include="Resources\Icons\icon8.png" />
            var evaluatedInclude = projectItem.EvaluatedInclude;
        }
```

**UPDATE**

This should give a general idea how to do certain tasks with project files.

Comment: it is noob question,but how to view result of itemsToCopy?
foreach(ProjectItm pr in itemsToCopy)
{
Consoles.WriteLine(pr.toString()); ?
}

Comment: ok.just like this:Console.WriteLine("evaluatedInclude "+evaluatedInclude);

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent element of `CopyToOutputDirectory` tag via it's `Parent` property. Also don't forget to get resources which are copied if newer:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var resources = from r in xdoc.Descendants("Resource")
                select (string)r.Attribute("Include");

var copiedContent = from c in xdoc.Descendants("CopyToOutputDirectory")
                    where (string)c == "Always" || (string)c == "PreserveNewest"
                    select (string)c.Parent.Attribute("Include");
```